# Animate Fabric js using GSAP?

Tags: javascript, canvas, css-animations, fabricjs, gsap

I have been playing with the Fabric.js library for a little while. What like about it is the ease of transforming objects and a couple more.

I am wondering if there is a plugin or any way to animate Fabric elements using GSAP?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by passing the fabric objects into the GSAP

```
const tl = new TimelineLite();
tl.staggerFromTo(
   [fabricObject], 
   1, 
  {left: -config.width}, 
  {left: config.width, onUpdate: () => canvas.renderAll()}, 
  0.4);
```