# Animating fabric.js object using gsap

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, gsap

Have working a fabric.js and gsap recently. Am trying to animate a fabric object with gsap using the object id but its not been working for me. I came across this post here [Animate Fabric js using GSAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324061/animate-fabric-js-using-gsap/50897448#50897448) but its not working fro me. Here is my code

```
const t2 = new TimelineLite();
t2.to($('#'+id), 1.75, {x: 200, ease: Quad.easeInOut,  onUpdate: () => canvas.renderAll()});
t2.play();
```

Comment: I saw a post that does it here https://greensock.com/forums/topic/17164-drawsvg-for-fabric-js/ . But I want to be able to do so using the object id but its not working. Any help

Comment: Check this [demo](http://fabricjs.com/animation-easing)